# Compiling Tux Rider

Tags: ios, build

Tux Rider is an iPhone port of the famous Tux Racer game.  As it's GPL software, the source is available on the [author's website](http://www.barlow-server.com/tuxriderworldchallenge/).  I downloaded the source, but can't get it to compile as it's missing resources.  Specifically, I get the following compile errors:

```
Rider: No such file or directory
World:  No such file or directory
Challenge:  No such file or directory
v1.1:  No such file or directory
```

I can't find any contact information for the author, and I'd like to be able to build my own version of the app.  I have a iPhone SDK and it seems like modifying a working game would be a good intro into learning OpenGL.  Has anyone had any success in getting this game to compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the error, I'm going to guess that you untarred into a directory named "Tux Rider World Challenge v1.1", and something in the build scripts or the Makefile is not quoting path arguments correctly. Try moving the source into a directory that has no spaces *anywhere* in its full path name, then repeating the build process.

Comment: +1, Highly likely that it's a screwup with space in the pathname rather than nefarious license violations.

Answer (score 2):

If you're goal is simply to learn OpenGL, I would strongly recommend **not** trying this right now. Why?

- You're going to be spending your time chasing down all of the things that won't compile correctly for the iPhone SDK, and my gut feeling that in a game the size of Tux Racer, there are going to be a lot of them. If you don't know OpenGL to begin with, it's going to make your job 100x harder.
- OpenGL on the iPhone ([OpenGL ES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES)) is a subset of standard OpenGL. I'd imagine that unless Tux Racer was written strictly against OpenGL ES, which I very much doubt, you're going to have to spend a lot of time coming up with OpenGL ES equivalent ways of doing things, and if you don't know OpenGL you will again be making your job 100x harder.

If you want to learn OpenGL on the iPhone, I highly recommend this blog series: [iPhone OpenGL ES Tutorial Series](http://web.me.com/smaurice/AppleCoder/iPhone_OpenGL/Archive.html). It's very informative, very well written, and is focused on writing OpenGL code for the iPhone itself. Good luck!

Comment: Tux Racer _has_ been ported to the iPhone.  If the author released the full source, I would have a complete working game to look at.

Comment: That's what I get for answering questions when I wake up, haha. I clearly did not read your original question well enough, I apologize for that :-)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this port breaks the GPLv2 terms and conditions, but I'm not a lawyer.

Read the [license](http://www.fsf.org/licensing/licenses/info/GPLv2.html) carefully and report it to http://gpl-violations.org and let them have a look at it too. The identity of the port author can't stay hidden (as Apple must have it) in case that the Free Software Foundation decides to take legal action.

Making money on compiled and packaged GPL products is nothing new. But it must be done while not violating the license, otherwise it's just greed.

Comment: It actually doesn't comply with a lot of things if I'm not. But I'll name one, an easy one: `Also add information on how to contact you by electronic and paper mail.`. As there is no contact information with the source or on the web-site, the author fails right there. Also if there is no possibility to actually compile the program and run it, as parts are missing. Then he fails on all "four essential freedoms" according to The Free Software Definition, which are formalized in legal terms in the GPLv2 license.

Comment: Now you have one copy paste failure from the GPLv2 license and some homework to do as well. He basically fails all over. The resources used are also GPLv2 licensed, and if they are missing it's a violation.

Comment: "Also add information on how to contact you by electronic and paper mail" is after the words "END OF TERMS AND CONDITIONS" because it's not a requirement. The app compiles just fine and includes all of the changed resources for the iPhone version. The whole Apple signing business is troublesome, but my understanding is that the GPLv2 *doesn't* protect against it.

Comment: It's under "How to Apply These Terms to Your New Programs", so I assume it's a requirement. If it's correct that resources which are GPL licensed are not included in the download, then it's a license break. Anyway, letting the people at GPL Violations have a look at it can never hurt. They are the license experts.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is more than 1 source file you need to obtain however, bear in mind that even if you can get this to compile you won't be able to load it onto your iPhone without being a paid-up iPhone developer. If you just want to play this game on your iPhone then I suggest you buy it through the App Store, it'll be a lot cheaper than the $99 to join the iPhone developer programme.